# AWS Command Line: What "Outbound connections on 443 must be enabled" means?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tcp, aws-cli

Network Newbie here.

**Background**

I am trying to use the AWS Command Line utility to connect to my instances on the AWS cloud.

**Problem**

When I try a simple command (from either local machine or EC2) such as...

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

I get...

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.sa-east-1a.amazonaws.com/"
```

Which is fine and dandy because according to the [AWS Command Line User Manual](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-set-up.html) I should take note of:

> The AWS CLI makes API calls to services over HTTPS. Outbound connections 
>   on TCP port 443 must be enabled in order to perform calls.

But what that is suppose to mean in the first place? I find the above statement as clear as a glass of muddy water.

1) Should I go to the 'Security Group' of my instance and set inbound rules to 'HTTPS TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0'? (Doesn't work)

2) Or set outbound rules and set 'HTTPS TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0' ? (Doesn't work)

3) Does the above statement has anything to do with the 'Security Groups'?

4) If it doesn't has to then, what should I do in my machine in order to 'enable the port 443. That being said...

5) Should I RUN the AWS Command Line utility from my local machine or from my EC2 remote server?

I'd appreciate some guidance so I can start solving my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're running `describe-instances` on your local machine, right? Not on an EC2 instance?

Comment: Hi, tedder42! I'm running aws ec2 describe-instances on both machines (local and EC2). Both give me the "Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.sa-east-1a.amazonaws.com/" error message. Sorry I wasn't clear. I edited my question to make clear I'm running the command from both machines.

Comment: you have your region configured as "sa-east-1a", but the **region** is actually "sa-east-1". Your **availability zones** are sa-east-1a, sa-east-1b, etc.

Comment: Thank goodness entries are closed for the Darwin's Award 2015 competition. Thank you very much, tedder42! I'll accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: Done. I'm sure I've done worse :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have your region configured as "sa-east-1a", but the **region** is actually "sa-east-1". Your **availability zones** are sa-east-1a, sa-east-1b, etc.

Comment: one might expect aws cli would validate the region and give a meaningful error  :)

Comment: `cat ~/.aws/config` to see the region configured for you. changing the file directly will solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, the tutorial on the AWS isn't clear. There is no mention of dropping the letter from the end of the region name.

Comment: This helped me a lot.